# ANTEK HDD case; remove the ACTIVITY LED?

Tags: external-hard-drive

The bright blue led stays on steady and blinks when accessed [external storage}. What will happen if I clip one of the leads? Will there be a detrimental result?
Why would I do this?: The light stays on even when the computer is asleep; it is very annoying to other users in the room; and it is of no conceivable use to me.

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYA20.jpg)
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCKDU.jpg)

Comment: Or just use tape to cover the light?... There shouldn't be any negative side effect from removing the LED.

Comment: I imagine that would depend on which lead you clip...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clip it. Or, as Attie mentions in the comment, cover it with a piece of electrical tape if you don't want to open the drive enclosure.

Comment: Or paint over it with black enamel paint.